# How to equal height of floated li's

Tags: html, css

Consider the following simple menu:

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.floated {
  float: left;
}

.buttonA {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonB {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="floated">
    <div class="buttonA">Option 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="floated">
    <div class="buttonB">Option 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="floated">
    <div class="buttonA">Option 3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make all floated buttons same height (equals the one that has bigger height), hiding the yellow background below `Option 1` and `Option 3`?

How can I remove the extra yellow at the right of the menu?

Comment: is it okay if you use display as flex?

Comment: Is there a reason for different paddings? buttonA has 10px padding buttonB has 20px

Comment: @Mendes Can you use js/jQuery?

Comment: No. Pure CSS/HTML

Comment: Almost answered this, but it doesn't make sense. Unless you want to make designers mad. Why would you have buttons with different paddings? The texts don't line up.

Comment: @Mendes You can't use flex, fixed height, equal padding. I assume your best bet would be find the tallest element with JS and assign the height of all the others to that.

Comment: Guys, as I've explained this is a snippet of a much bigger application where I'm isolating the functionality I need implemented. I cannot use flex nor JS. I need a pure CSS solution to equal those heights (without fixing it). If this is impossible, than I will consider a second approach where I need to review the whole application. For not this is what I need...

Comment: Why would dropdown and flex be inherently incompatible? Flexbox, like use of floats, are use for positioning of the parent element and you can definitely implement drop downs regardless of how the parent elements are laid out.

Comment: After rechecking... Flex accepted as a solution...